# iPhone 6 won't work unless plugged in

Tags: iphone

My iPhone 6 fell down the toilet two days ago but now it works fine. It charges fine when I plug it in, but once I take it out, it shuts off, and tells me there is not enough battery, when it was at a 96 percent. When I plug it in again, it works perfectly and it is at the same percentage that I had left it at. What can I do?

Comment: Take it to a repair shop.

Answer (score 1):

From your question I'm assuming the iPhone battery worked well prior to being dropped in the toilet.

It looks like you need to have the battery replaced.  If you have AppleCare, you should go to and Apple Store or contact Apple support to have the battery properly assessed and, if needed, replaced.  See [this Apple page](https://support.apple.com/iphone/repair/battery-power) for info on replacing the battery.  I would recommend going this route as it appears to be the lowest cost option.

If you don't have AppleCare, you can go to any 3rd party that you trust to replace the battery.  You can also go to Apple to pay to have them replace it.

If you're handy, you can also [replace the battery yourself](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPhone+6+Battery+Replacement/29363?revisionid=HEAD).

Answer (score 1):

A couple of months ago Apple initiated a iPhone battery replacement program. You can take advantage of this to have your battery replaced for some nominal cost, much less than what a normal battery costs. If you just want to replace your battery I'd call the nearest Apple Store and set up an appointment to get your battery replaced. Be sure to ask about their battery replacement program.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a battery related issue. It is recommended you get in touch with Apple Authorised Service Provider to get the issue identified and resolved. It may help if your iPhone is covered under limited warranty or Apple Care, but be forewarned that [Liquid damages to iPhone are not covered under warranty](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204104).

For starters, you can contact [Apple Online Support](https://getsupport.apple.com) where you can discuss your issue with Apple Support Representative over Phone or Chat and arrive at possible solutions.

On the [Apple Online Support website](https://getsupport.apple.com), select `iPhone -> Battery Power & Charging -> Battery questions or troubleshooting`. You can opt to chat with the support representative or request for a phone call.

[image]

Alternatively, you can find a local authorized service provider and get the device physically inspected.

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure there’s no warranty if you drowned it.

Comment: Presumed innocent until proven guilty. ;-)

Comment: FYI: iPhone has water penetration indicators inside. As soon as it is opened, Apple will know it has had water inside.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @cmason :). That comment was made in a wee-bit of a comic sense. The answer duly conveys the fact regarding non-coverage of liquid damages. Your comment will further help in conveying it prominently.

Comment: You might call a plumber,  You did drop it into a toilet. See if a plunger will help.